# Pinching problem

Tags: mesh, vertices, workflow, subdivision-surface, topology

[image]

So I have a 3D model with the following problem - one vertex is kind of holding too much topology in once. I am not entirely sure as to how I can fix this pinching issue (maybe separate it, but how exactly?).

With Subd:
[image: Subd]

Without Subd:
[image: No Subd]

[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "holding too much topology in once", maybe show your reference object?

Comment: The selected vertex on the images above is problematic - I need the left part (which has to be separate from this vertex and should have its own vertex) to be a bit on the left, without being connected to the right part (because else if I try to move this one vertex, the whole thing moves). In other words, I am trying to add another vertex which would act as a separator between these 2 parts of the 3D model and hold the left part so that I can move it freely

Comment: Your tomology is messy, maybe show your reference object

Comment: Sorry but I don't know as to what you mean by reference object. Do you mean the .blend file? I have put it in the post for it to be downloaded (but if you mean the concept art, I don't have such)

Comment: I mean do you have an image of the real object that you're trying to model? Your topology is very messy, maybe model it another way?

Comment: Nah sorry I don't really have an image. Idk if it makes it clearer, but I'm trying to make the selected vertex from the photo to NOT stick to the right side of the 3D model in the pictures above